# Java construction issue findmissing element

Tags: java

I have to find a missing element from the array where array has got values from <0, N>.

For example: int tablica[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5};, missing number is 4.

I have got 3 implementations of this code, but...
Only one gives me output, why?

Why naiveFindMissing() and optimalFindMissing() don't give any output?

```
public class Zad2_Selftraining {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        findMissing();
        naiveFindMissing();
        optimalFindMissing();

    }


    public static void findMissing() {
        int tablica[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5};

        for(int i = 0; i<tablica.length;i++ ){
            if (tablica[i] != i){
                System.out.println("Missing: " + i);
                return;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Everything is correct");
        return;
    }

    private static int naiveFindMissing() {
        int array[] = {0,1,2,4,5,6,7};
        int missing = 0;
        boolean elementFound;
        for (int elementToFind = 0; elementToFind <= array.length; elementToFind++) {
            elementFound = false;
            for (int elementInArray : array) {
                if (elementToFind == elementInArray) {
                    elementFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!elementFound) {
                missing = elementToFind;
                break;
            }
        }
        return missing;
    }


    private static int optimalFindMissing() {
        int array[] = {0,1,2,4,5,6,7};
        int expectedSum = (array.length + 1) * array.length / 2;
        int actualSum = 0;
        for (int element : array) {
            actualSum += element;
        }
        return expectedSum - actualSum;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you have System.out.println statement only in first method. The other two methods just return result without printing it